# Enter EditText on a Fragment and fill also all other Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, android-viewpager

I have implemented the Android Tutorial from the [Android Training Site](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) and everything works so far.

Inside of a `Fragment`, I added an `EditText` field, where the user can enter a simple text string.

What I want to achieve is: If the user entered something, and then swipes to left or right, the input should be "copied" the new fragment as well.

As in the training, I have got a ScreenSlidePageFragment.java class and a ScreenSlideActivity.java class.

I've implemented an Interface in the ScreenSlidePageFragment, [as mentioned here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html):

```
Communicator mCallback;

public interface Communicator {
    void sendData(String inpString);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        mCallback = (Communicator) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + "must Implement OnEditChangedListener");
    }
}
```

But at the end, I just managed to receive it on the ScreenSlideActivity. How do I update a specified fragment? 
In ScreenSlideActivity I tried to send it back to the new fragment.

```
@Override
public void sendData(String inpString) {
       WHATFRAGMENT.changeData(inpString);
}
```

But how do I access another one (WHATFRAGMENT), which are created in the ScreenSlidePagerAdapter:

```
 @Override
 public Fragment getItem(int position) {
     return NewReservationSlidePageFragment.create(position);
 }
```

Do I need to create a whole Fragment and overwrite the new position? Or is it even necessary to work around the Activity? Is it possible to use `FragmentTransaction` somehow?

What would be the simplest solution for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve with your `interface` and `public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)`

Add one more method in your interface like this,

```
public interface Communicator {
    void sendData(String inpString);
    String getData();
}
```

And in you activity create one String variable Globally to store the value.

And assign the data coming form `sendData` in that

```
@Override
public void sendData(String inpString) {
    this.value = inpString;
       //WHATFRAGMENT.changeData(inpString);
}
```

and implement `getData` too in your Activity

```
@Override
public void getData() {
    return this.value;
}
```

Add `setUserVisibleHint` in your fragment

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    if(isVisibleToUser) {
        mCallback.sendData("[string from your edit text]");
    } else {
        String value = mCallback.getData();
    }
}
```

Now you can see the data which you edited in one fragment can show in other visible fragment.

Comment: The `getData()` method isn't necessary. Each `Fragment` will call `sendData()` when it is being removed from the `FragmentManager`, probably in `onPause()`. Probably the `Activity` implements the interface and forwards the data to the next `Fragment`.

Comment: If you are using view pager **onPause** and **OnResume** will not get call in that time we should use **setUserVisibleHint** method only.

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran Thanks a lot, now it is working. Didn't knew the `setUserVisibleHint()` before.
But at one point i got a behavior, which could confuse the User: If the textfield is changed on one of the other Fragments, and swiped back, the Data is not overwritten. It remains the "old" String, even if i try to clear it before: `myEditTxt.getText().clear()`

Comment: Just for the records: solved my problem in my previous comment by clearing the EditText straight after `sendData()` and not at `onCreateView()` or somewhere else...